# Wildfly 10. Deploy an aplication on a specific server

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, war

I need to have an ability make several applications listen on different ports, but in the certain situation some of these applications must listen on the same port. I can change all configs, but I can't reassemble WAR files.

I've read this article ["Application deployment"](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Application+deployment) but still perplexed. Can it be done on standalone server? If it is possible, what configs should I make?

UPD
May be I sould change the question. Is there any way to set up a specific virtual server for an application by a deployment descriptor?

Comment: do you want this on the same JBoss instance or separate instance?

Comment: I'd prefer to do this on the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

To create create a different http listeners on the same wildfy instance, you will need to adjust your configuration file by adding the new `http-listener`.

Add, just below `<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>`, in the undertow subsystem your new listener `<http-listener name="customerPort" socket-binding="customerPort"/>`

Then in your `socket-binding-group` (usually at the end of the configuration file), add the socket binding referencing `customerPort` above `<socket-binding name="customerPort" port="2323"/>`

Hope this help solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I know it. But it doesn't solve my problem. Fot example I have two applications: app1.war and app2.war. I can put them on different vistual servers with own ports through jboss-web.xml, but further it will be impossible to put them on the same virtual server.